# Setting Domain Name on IIS6

Tags: iis, dns, iis-6, windows-server-2003, domain-name

I am setting up web applications on a development box (which I have remote access to) and I am looking to set the **domain name**, since we currently have to use an IP address to access the sites.

The server is **Windows 2003**, so I am using **IIS 6**. What are the steps to configure this?

I have searched Google, but I am possibly searching on the wrong terms as I can't find anything with steps to configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the hostheader on the property pages of the website (Web Site tab, Advanced Button).

Look [here](http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/)